# No version prompt when running maven-release-plugin inside Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven, m2e, maven-release-plugin

When I run `maven release:prepare` from the command line I'm prompted for the release version,  developer version and SCM tag. This is good. What is not so good is when I do the same from inside Eclipse. Using an m2e run configuration I set the same goal but instead of prompting me for the version information it automatically sets them to some defaults. The defaults are pretty good but sometimes I want explicit control.

There are many developers on this project and asking them to drop out to command lines or fiddle with shared run configurations is not ideal. Maybe this has nothing to do with the Maven Release Plugin and is more to do with input prompts in general. Are there any other examples of Maven plugins prompting for input during execution inside Eclipse?

I'm using SpringSource Tool Suite 2.9 (old!) configured to use an external Maven 3.0.3 with m2e 0.12.1.

Answer (score 0):

This is normal. The Eclipse plugin for Release will automatically release the version set in your POM, and set the next development version to +0.0.1 of that.

I'm used to using the release plugin from inside Eclipse, and when I used it from command prompt I was surprised when I was prompted for version :p